# Can't use --mode in virsh shutdown

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Any mode gives me:

```
error: unsupported flags (0x4) in function qemuDomainShutdownFlags
```

Is there a package I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the qemu only support agent and acpi.
signal and initctl are used by LXC
paravirt is used by Xen